# My passphrase does not work anymore?

Tags: ssh

For a long time I am using my SSH public key to log in many many servers.
But today, after rebooting my ubuntu 16.04 (let's call it 'A'), my passphrase is not accepted  anymore (in my case I have NO passphrase, but ssh asks one). First, I believed some kind of private/public file corruption, but I checked the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files : there are identical with a backup I made sometimes ago.

I have another computer running ubuntu 16.04 (let's call it 'B'): if I import id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from 'A' to 'B': it does not work neither, ssh is asking a passphrase despite there is None.

At the opposite, if I import the keys pair that was working on 'B' to the computer 'A', they are still working on 'A'

So it really seems that my usual keys from 'A' are not working anymore everywhere ! how this can be possible ? Is there a expiration date somewhere ?

I try many things :

- Change the passphrase, but it requires the old one that is not accepted :

  ```
  $ ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa Enter old passphrase:  Failed to load key /home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
  ```
- check the .ssh dir and keys files access rights : all is ok.
- ssh-add does not help
- starting ssh-agent does not help
- deleting and recreating the password wallet does not help
- Try ssh in console mode (Ctrl+F1) : not better
- If I create a brand new keys pair, it works, but I want to use my usual key pair in order to not have to change the public key everywhere (100 computers/servers)

Do you have an idea ?

**NOTE 1 :**

I disabled gnome-keyring and rebooted to reduce the problem, `ssh -vvv` asks for a passphrase but it should not :

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:cKYfSV1Glzq2dDgJQ/t6A4c5kHnQTWgrvLaKvgcHp7o
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:cKYfSV1Glzq2dDgJQ/t6A4c5kHnQTWgrvLaKvgcHp7o
Enter passphrase for key '/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
```

At the server side in debug mode :

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/elapouya/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:cKYfSV1Glzq2dDgJQ/t6A4c5kHnQTWgrvLaKvgcHp7o
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:cKYfSV1Glzq2dDgJQ/t6A4c5kHnQTWgrvLaKvgcHp7o
Enter passphrase for key '/home/elapouya/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug1: Trying private key: /home/elapouya/.ssh/id_dsa
```

`ssh-add`, `ssh-agent` don't help

**NOTE 2** :

I just discovered that my (very) old private key begins with :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,42F493B90AF9B59D

f3sgdsomething...
```

When I generate new key pair, the private key does not begin with the same thing :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAuBMNSvZJFY7/395IJ3tUkyRwCOnDeT2AuaXYJs7diLPHHJEN
```

My old key pair has been generated on an ubuntu 10.xx then I copied it after re-installing a brand new ubuntu 16.04 on my computer : may be the format of my old key is not recognized any more on my ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: connect with `ssh -vvv`. Edit the output and the corresponding lines from your servers auth.log into the question. Also, the exact error message could be helpful, depending on the cause the wording can be slightly different.

Comment: Are you using the right character set on your host? Have you confirmed your password by writing it in plaintext first?

Comment: @Gerald : I added the Note 1 in the question

Comment: @Starlord : In fact, there no passphrase at all, but ssh is asking for one (graphically with gnome or textually in console mode after enabling ssh-agent).

Comment: There are some suggestions in [this question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762541/ubuntu-16-04-ssh-sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation) you can check.

Comment: Unfortunately I looked at this page before opening the question ...